# Getting navigation path of a session using Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I would like to know if it's possible to get the navigation path and timing spent on each page and some information about the client (browser, os, source) using the Google Analytics API. I could store the user id using Google Tag Manager DataLayer.

Is possible to get that information using Google Analytics API? (Another service is also welcome)

Answer (score 1):

The [Google analytics api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) supports a large number of dimensions and metrics which can be extracted.  You should consult the [dimensions and metrics explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) to see if these suite your needs.   Your user id should be saved as a custom dimension if you wish to be able to extract that.

1. [User Timings - Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user_timings)
2. [Platform or Device - Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=platform_or_device)